# animation in wpf

Tags: wpf

I am a beginner in WPF.
I want to display my form on every tick.
but it's only displaying once.
when I debug this, it's hitting the `this.topmost=true` in timer tick event, but 
it is not displaying the window.
I am not sure what's wrong with this code.

```
public partial class Window1 : Window
    {
        public Window1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer timer = new System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer();

                timer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 2, 0);

                timer.Tick += tick;                  

                timer.Start();                   

        }
        private void tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            this.Topmost = true;//display the form
            this.Show();

        }
    }
```

```
    <Border BorderThickness="1" Background="Beige" BorderBrush="Black" CornerRadius="10">
        <StackPanel Margin="20">

            <CheckBox Content="Checkable" Margin="5 5 0 5" />
            <Button Content="Clickable" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
        </StackPanel>
    </Border>

<!-- Animation -->
        <Grid.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="FrameworkElement.Loaded">
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(ScaleTransform.ScaleY)">
                            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="0"/>
                            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.0" Value="1"/>
                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)">
                            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:2" Value="1"/>
                            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:8" Value="0"/>
                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger>
        </Grid.Triggers>
```

Comment: I am a little confused about what you are trying to do. The form is being initialized and shown during your InitializeComponent Method. All your Timer is doing is making it the Topmost Window. It is already visible at this time.

Comment: A completely unrelated bit of advice (since you mentioned you're new to WPF), instead of using `new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 2, 0)`, use `TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2)`. It makes code easier to read :)

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you want. I have taken the WPF window that you wanted to show to your client and moved it into another form. I then created another startup form that is hidden and runs the timer showing your animation periodically.

Startup Form:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="10" Width="10" ShowInTaskbar="False" Visibility="Hidden" >

    <Grid />

</Window>
```

Startup Form Code Behind

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{

    Window1 cyclicWindow;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        cyclicWindow = new Window1();
        cyclicWindow.Show();
        cyclicWindow.Topmost = true;
        System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer timer = new System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer();
        timer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 20, 0);
        timer.Tick += tick;
        timer.Start();
    }

    private void tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (cyclicWindow != null)
        {
            cyclicWindow.Close() ;
        }

        cyclicWindow = new Window1();
        cyclicWindow.Show();
        cyclicWindow.Topmost = true;

    }

}
```

Cycling Window:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.Window1"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="Window1" Height="200" Width="300" Name="Main"
        ShowInTaskbar="False" WindowStyle="None" Background="Transparent" >

    <Grid Name="Base" Height="112">
        <Border BorderThickness="1" Background="Beige" BorderBrush="Black" CornerRadius="10">
            <StackPanel Margin="20">

                <CheckBox Content="Checkable" Margin="5 5 0 5" />
                <Button Content="Clickable" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
            </StackPanel>
        </Border>

        <!-- Animation -->
        <Grid.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="FrameworkElement.Loaded">
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Main" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(ScaleTransform.ScaleY)">
                            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="0"/>
                            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.0" Value="1"/>
                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Main" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)">
                            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:2" Value="1"/>
                            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:8" Value="0"/>
                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger>
        </Grid.Triggers>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Cycling Window Code Behind:

```
public partial class Window1 : Window
{
    public Window1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        AllowsTransparency = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you very much for your reply.
i want this window shoud popup for every 20 min after user logged in and auto hide not forever.

Comment: @LillyW I have adjusted my answer to account for the additional information you gave in your comment. Does it do what you want?

Comment: @LillyW No problem, I took it as a challenge it gave me something to chew on while I was doing yard work . If the answer works for you please don't forget to accept it.

Comment: this application using a lot of memory. I mean for every 20 min  the memory usage is increasing(1000k).can you pls tell how to resolve the memory leak.

Comment: Try adding `cyclicWindow = null;` after `cyclicWindow.Close();` that should remove any references to the form and allow the Garbage Collector to collect it. If that doesn't work try adding `GC.Collect();` after the null statement.

Comment: I believe it is because you have the animation in your cyclicWindow and when you close the window there are references that are still being held on to. You may want to create your animation in your code behind that way you can stop it in the form closing event.